# replacing the break lines by inserting new row in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to split from single row to multiple rows? There is a new line break in the ColumnC.

[image]

So if click edit I'll get this:
[image]

Finally got it used this below: 
select it.ColumnA, it.ColumnB, REGEXP_SUBSTR((rtrim(translate(Lower(it.ColumnC), chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), '$'), '$')),'[^$]+', 1, LEVEL) 
from myTable it CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR((rtrim(translate(Lower(it.ColumnC), chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), '$'), '$')),'[^$]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY it.ColumnA, it.ColumnB, REGEXP_SUBSTR((rtrim(translate(Lower(it.ColumnC), chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), '$'), '$')),'[^$]+', 1, LEVEL)

Comment: Even [more](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2290), and [more](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/)

Comment: It is not duplicated question. All the link do not answer the question.

Comment: Finally got it used this below:

select it.ColumnA, it.ColumnB, REGEXP_SUBSTR((rtrim(translate(Lower(it.ColumnC), chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), '$'), '$')),'[^$]+', 1, LEVEL) 
from myTable it
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR((rtrim(translate(Lower(it.ColumnC), chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), '$'), '$')),'[^$]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY it.ColumnA, it.ColumnB, REGEXP_SUBSTR((rtrim(translate(Lower(it.ColumnC), chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13), '$'), '$')),'[^$]+', 1, LEVEL)

Comment: Your solution does not handle NULL list elements. Try deleting an element while keep the carriage return. It will return 2 rows instead of 3 as expected. Try this: `with myTable(ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) as (
  select 1, 'king', 'Dog
Cat 
Dog,cat' from dual
)
select it.ColumnA, it.ColumnB, 
  lower(REGEXP_SUBSTR(it.ColumnC, '(.*?)('||chr(10)||'|$)', 1, LEVEL) ) ColumnC
from myTable it 
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(it.ColumnC, chr(10))+1 
GROUP BY it.ColumnA, it.ColumnB, REGEXP_SUBSTR(it.ColumnC, '(.*?)('||chr(10)||'|$)', 1, LEVEL)
order by ColumnC;`